# How to call multiple quotes from IEX Cloud API

Tags: api, cloud, quotes, stock, elixir-iex

I am trying to use IEX Cloud to get stock quotes for multiple stocks with one API call.

Here is my api call for Apple,Facebook, and Tesla.  What am I doing wrong?
https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&types=quote?token=MY_TOKEN_HERE

The Error Message returned from the API is this:

"types" required with a valid value

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem was question mark between 'quote' and token. It should be '&' instead. I replicated your error with question mark, but with & it works just fine.

Here is what works for me: https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=quote&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

if you want to retrieve just the latest price, you can use following call:

https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?&types=price&symbols=aapl,fb,tsla&token=YOUR_TOKEN_HERE

You can learn more at this link: [How do I query multiple symbols or data types in one API Call?](https://intercom.help/iexcloud/en/articles/2852094-how-do-i-query-multiple-symbols-or-data-types-in-one-api-call) (for production you use cloud.iexapis.com instead of sandbox)

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much!  That was the problem!  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

as of 2nd-July-2022,

This is how I structured my URL for a batch request.

```js
const tickerArray = ["AAPL", "META", "GOOGL", "TSLA"];

`https://cloud.iexapis.com/v1/stock/market/batch?symbols=${tickerArray.toString().toLowerCase()}&types=quote&token=${process.env.IEXCLOUD_API_KEY}`
```